# Formula for gaussian curvature of a holomorphic curve in complex 2-space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Define h : ℂ → ℂ<sup>2</sup> via

h(z)  =  (f(z), g(z)),

where f, g : ℂ → ℂ are analytic functions such that the complex velocity h'(z) = (f'(z), g'(z)) ∈ ℂ<sup>2</sup> is never equal to (0,0). Suppose further that h is an embedding of ℂ into ℂ<sup>2</sup>.

Then the image h(ℂ) is a smooth (C<sup>∞</sup>) real surface at each of its points h(z), deriving its metric in the standard way as a submanifold of ℂ<sup>2</sup> = ℝ<sup>4</sup>.  As such it has a well-defined gaussian curvature K(z) at each point h(z) ∈ ℂ<sup>2</sup>.

After finding a formula for K(z) in no book or paper that I was able to access, I calculated such a formula as

K(z) =  -2 |h''(z) ^ h'(z)|<sup>2</sup> / |h'(z)|<sup>6</sup>,

where h''(z) ^ h'(z) is shorthand for f''(z) g'(z) - g''(z) f'(z).

**Question**: Is this formula well known?  Can anyone give a reference for where it can be found?

(Note: I am **not** looking for formulas from which this one can be derived.)

*Remark*: We could have replaced the domain by a nonempty open subset of ℂ and asked only that h be an immersion, but those refinements seemed to obscure the main point.

Comment: I think it is well-known, as are the cases $\mathbb{C}^2$ (or $\mathbb{CP}^2$) equipped with the Fubini-Study metric.  I can't give you a reference though.  They are almost immediate from the chern connection matrix.

Comment: Perhaps try papers of Linda Ness in the late 70‘s.

Comment: Any chance the math could be rewritten in LaTeX?

Comment: This is a formula that is too specialized to be mentioned in most textbooks. I’m sure it’s been used and appears in at least one paper somewhere, but I wouldn’t know how to find them. And since the derivation is straightforward, the proof is probably left to the reader.

Comment: How did you prove this exactly?  The general formula for Gaussian curvature in terms of the metric is complicated but in isothermal coordinates $f^2(x,y)(dx^2+dy^2)$ it simplifies to $K=-\Delta_{LB}\ln f$ where $\Delta_{LB}$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator.  Since your map is holomorphic, it provides isothermal coordinates and therefore the simpler formula applies.  I haven't checked the details but the formula you provide does not seem to be that surprising.  Interestingly, it is the square of the formula for the geodesic curvature of a curve.  I am not sure I have a ready explanation othis.